# How to deal with missing value in dependent variable of prediction model?

Tags: predictive-models, missing-data, multiple-imputation, sensitivity-analysis

I am trying to build a prediction model from longitudinal study after intervention. So after intervention, we followup patients 1,3, and 6 months later to see if they are cured or not. So dependent variable is cure or not, then independent variable is patients' information at baseline(sevirity level, age, etc)

I found some missing data in both a dependent variable and some independent variables. for dependent variable, missing could happen as MCAR because many of them just moved from study setting. For independent variable, missing mechanism is not sure.

Since the dependent variable is the outcome at the final follow-up from longitudinal analysis, can I do a sensitivity analysis based on the outcome at the previous follow-up after doing multiple imputations for an independent variable? Then I will see the robustness of the model for both.

Comment: Greetings and welcome to CV! It may help to provide the following information: what kind of longitudinal analysis are you doing? Why is the data missing (is it totally random or because of some influence)? How much is missing? This may help people provide an answer for you, as the question is unfortunately lacking some context.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I added some info, but basically missing mechanism is not sure, and since my sample size is small 90, so don;t want to go for complete case analysis. Missing is 5 out of 90 in dependent variable, I have 10 patients with at least one missingness in both independent and dependent variables.